# Where do I go from Cerulean City?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green, pokemon-lets-go

I’m playing “Pokémon Red” and “Let’s go Eevee”, and am stuck at Cerulean City in both games. I got the gym badge from Misty and helped Bill. Where do I go to get to the next town or city?

Furthermore, in Pokémon red, I have a Bike voucher, but I can’t figure out how to get a bike. When I talk to the bike shop owner, he says

> Oh, that’s...
>
> A BIKE VOUCHER!
>
> Ok! Here you go!
>
> You better make room for this!

I don’t seem to get a bicycle though. The bike voucher is still in my items as well.

How do I get the bicycle and where do I go from there?

Comment: Okay, while it's the same city, these are different games, you should likely ask a separate question for each.

Comment: "You better make room for this!" sounds like you've got too many items in your inventory. Just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a house, slightly south east of the bridge, that has been robbed. If you go inside, then you will find a hole in a wall that you can go through to go outside. Go around the city and head south from there until you get to the next city (you have to go through an underground tunnel).

As for the bike, it turned out that I had to free up inventory space. This confused me quite a bit, as I expected that the bike would overwrite the inventory slot that had the voucher and did not think that there would be a limited space inventory.

Answer (score 2):

You need to head south on route 5 and take the underground passage to route 6 and Vermilion City.  There is a gym in this city which is your next stop.

Not sure what is going on with the Bike voucher, I would try depositing/selling a few TM you are not using in the PC and try again.  In the original games you have limited space in your bag.

Comment: ^^ the 2nd issue is due to item carry capacity being reached, drop/use a few items and they'll get the bike